# Not able to align two elements beside each other in css

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner in front-end, and I'm trying to align "fruits" and "computers" beside each other, but in my code "computer" is below "fruits."

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: auto;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 33px auto;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.item {
  border: 4px;
  margin: 12px;
  padding: 12px 4px;
  background: rgb(197, 105, 105);
  border-radius: 12px;
}

#fruits {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  border: 3px solid darkblue;
}

#computer {
  width: 48%;
  border: 3px solid darkblue;
}

#stationary {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="fruits" class="item">
    <h3>Fruits</h3>
    <p id="fruitspara" class="para">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et nesciunt earum corporis ipsam, quaerat accusantium quae harum dicta facere ab, illo, molestias alias asperiores ea illum ducimus recusandae quidem praesentium.</p>

  </div>
  <div id="computer" class="item">
    <h3>Computer</h3>
    <p id="computerpara" class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias numquam recusandae deserunt earum asperiores quod harum tempora, eligendi amet quidem natus ab, laborum itaque quos. Laboriosam in eius doloribus aliquid?</p>
  </div>
  <div id="stationary" class="item">
    <h3>Stationary</h3>
    <p id="stationarypara" class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa, dolores exercitationem sint atque, saepe illum maiores obcaecati ratione doloremque quam laboriosam eum ad aperiam ab pariatur fuga explicabo esse aliquid.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This results in the following alignment:

[image]

I know the presentation is not good but this is just for practice. Please tell me what is the error.

Comment: you can use flexbox

Answer (score 1):

Both divs (fruits and computer) need to be floating for them to float next to each other. Alternatively, you could set them to inline-block.

But actually, flex (as the other commenter says) is a better solution for what I think you're trying to do

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The default display is block so divs take all the width. to be able to achieve what you want you can use flexbox :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Alignment</title>
    <style>
        *{
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .container{
            display:flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            width: auto;
            border: 3px solid black;
            margin: 33px auto;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        }
        .item{
            border:4px;
            margin: 12px;
            padding: 12px 4px;
            background:rgb(197, 105, 105);
            border-radius:12px;
        }
        #fruits{
            /*float: left;*/
            width: 48%;
            border:3px solid darkblue;
            
        }
        #computer{
            
            width: 48%;
            border:3px solid darkblue;
        }
        #stationary{
           /* float: left;*/
            width: 50%;
            border:3px solid darkblue;
        }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="fruits" class="item">
            <h3>Fruits</h3>
            <p id="fruitspara" class="para">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et nesciunt earum corporis ipsam, quaerat accusantium quae harum dicta facere ab, illo, molestias alias asperiores ea illum ducimus recusandae quidem praesentium.</p>

        </div>
        <div id="computer" class="item">
            <h3>Computer</h3>
            <p id="computerpara" class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias numquam recusandae deserunt earum asperiores quod harum tempora, eligendi amet quidem natus ab, laborum itaque quos. Laboriosam in eius doloribus aliquid?</p> 
        </div>
        <div id="stationary" class="item">
            <h3>Stationary</h3>
            <p id="stationarypara" class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa, dolores exercitationem sint atque, saepe illum maiores obcaecati ratione doloremque quam laboriosam eum ad aperiam ab pariatur fuga explicabo esse aliquid.</p> 
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and this is the result :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

⇝            width: 48%;

```
        width: auto;
        border: 3px solid black;
        margin: 33px auto;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;       
    }
    .item{
        border:4px;
        margin: 12px;
        padding: 12px 4px;
        background:rgb(197, 105, 105);
        border-radius:12px;
    }
    #fruits{
        float: left;
        width: 48%;
       position:absolute;
        border:3px solid darkblue;
    }
    #computer{
       margin-left: 50%;
       position:absolute;
       width: 48%;
       border:3px solid darkblue;
    }
    #stationary{
      margin-top: 20%;
      position: absolute;
      float: left;
      width: 48%;
      border:3px solid darkblue;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="fruits" class="item">
            <h3>Fruits</h3>
            <p id="fruitspara" class="para">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et
               nesciunt earum corporis ipsam, quaerat accusantium quae harum dicta facere ab, illo, molestias alias asperiores ea illum ducimus recusandae quidem praesentium.</p>
```

try this once

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```css
        *{
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .container{
            width: 100%;
            border: 3px solid black;
            margin: 33px auto;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        }
        .item{
            border:4px;
            margin: 12px;
            padding: 12px 4px;
            background:rgb(197, 105, 105);
            border-radius:12px;
        }
        #fruits{
            float: left;
            width: 45%;
            border:3px solid darkblue;
            
        }
        #computer{
           float: left;
            width: 45%;
            border:3px solid darkblue;
        }
        #stationary{
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            border:3px solid darkblue;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div id="fruits" class="item">
            <h3>Fruits</h3>
            <p id="fruitspara" class="para">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et nesciunt earum corporis ipsam, quaerat accusantium quae harum dicta facere ab, illo, molestias alias asperiores ea illum ducimus recusandae quidem praesentium.</p>

        </div>
        <div id="computer" class="item">
            <h3>Computer</h3>
            <p id="computerpara" class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias numquam recusandae deserunt earum asperiores quod harum tempora, eligendi amet quidem natus ab, laborum itaque quos. Laboriosam in eius doloribus aliquid?</p> 
        </div>
        <div id="stationary" class="item">
            <h3>Stationary</h3>
            <p id="stationarypara" class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa, dolores exercitationem sint atque, saepe illum maiores obcaecati ratione doloremque quam laboriosam eum ad aperiam ab pariatur fuga explicabo esse aliquid.</p> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've fixed your code but you should use Flexbox or Grid as Float is obsolete now. To learn about flex you can use this site [FlexFroggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com/)